# Plural of dialogue/statements?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

What would the correct grammar be for making statements plural?

Such as They showered her in "I'll miss you's."

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a matter of grammar but of style.

There is no clear style for this—although there are likely many style guides that will indicate one thing or another.

These are all possibilities I can think of that some people *might* use:

> "I'll miss you's."
>   "I'll miss you"s.
>   *I'll miss you*s.
>   *I'll miss yous*.
>   'I'll miss you'-s.
>   I'LL MISS YOUs.
>   "I'LL MISS YOU"s.
>   "I'LL MISS YOUs."
>   **I'll miss you**s.
>   **I'll miss yous**.

---

In this particular case, none of those look particularly natural to me.

I would likely rephrase the sentence to avoid the problem:

> They showered her in a chorus of "I'll miss you!"